# GPU support on preemtible workers VMs on Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Are the GPUs supported on preemptible workers VMs? [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/gpus#before_you_begin) claims:

> GPUs cannot be attached to preemptible virtual machines in Dataproc clusters.

but [latter section](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/gpus#attaching_gpus_to_clusters_2) mentions:

> Attach GPUs to the master and primary and preemptible worker nodes in a Dataproc cluster when creating the cluster using the `‑‑master-accelerator`, `‑‑worker-accelerator`, and `‑‑preemptible-accelerator` flags.

And [gcloud dataproc SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--preemptible-worker-accelerator) mentions that.

It is super confusing, could someone clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

GPUs are supported on preemptible workers in Dataproc cluster:

```sh
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster_name>
REGION=<region>
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --num-preemptible-workers=2 \
  --preemptible-worker-accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100
```

There are a bug right now that prevents attachment of the GPUs to preemptible VMs. It's already fixed and should be rolled out during the next week.